# How to work both wifi and Lan in the same network segment?

Tags: linux, wifi, lan

I'm using Linux+QT for my OS system.

And here is what I'm facing the problem.

My Lan IP address is `172.16.120.17` and my wifi IP address is `172.16.120.20`.

So I think they are in the same network segment.

Then I going to ping the address by using eth0.

And it works perfectly.

But When I ping it with wlan0 like below command.

```
ping -I wlan0 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

I can't ping the address.

After some testing, I find out that if I close down eth0 then wifi ping out as expect.(I'm doing with below command)

```
ifconfig eth0 down
```

If wifi and lan are in the different network segment then wifi and lan both can ping out as expect.

Why will this happened and how to fix it?

Or this is the normal phenomenon?

Thanks in Advanced!

Comment: This topic might be related to your issue: [How to have two network interfaces wifi and ethernet (as a backup) working together](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/212697/how-to-have-two-network-interfaces-wifi-and-ethernet-as-a-backup-working-toget)

Comment: I try it but it still cannot solve my problem.

Comment: Device bonding is the way to go.

Comment: @fmurphy how would binding for the case that Ethernet and WiFi are connected to different subnets?

Comment: Please flush the route table `ip route flush table main` then restart the network `systemctl restart networking`

Answer (score 2):

Specifying the interface is not enough, you need to specify the source IP. See the man page for ping:

> interface  is  either  an  address,  or an interface name.  If interface is an address, it sets source address to specified interface address.  If interface in an interface name, it sets source

It is very likely your ping is going out with the source IP of eth0 which is messing things up.