# Making network-manager prefer using the wifi connection

Tags: networking, networkmanager

I just added a powerline connection to my computer in case the wifi crashes again. It's really slow though and should only be used as a fallback.

When I'm connected to both the powerline ethernet and the wifi, it will communicate via ethernet. But I want it to use the wifi connection instead.

There is this answer from 6 years ago which kinda looks like it would help: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/212835/227331 but it uses `ifconfig` and I haven't been able to do this via the `ip` command

Here is it for reference:

```bsh
$ sudo modprobe bonding
$ sudo ifconfig bond0 192.168.0.1 netmask 255.255.0.0
$ sudo ifenslave bond0 eth0 wlan0
```

I tried to translate the mentioned command using this tutorial: https://www.andreafortuna.org/2017/05/22/how-to-use-the-ip-command-instead-of-ifconfig/

and came up with

```
sudo ip address add 192.168.0.1/16 dev bond0
```

but it says `Cannot find device "bond0"`

Comment: Can you post your `ip a` output? I am sure you have no `bond` configured. Also please show the output of `nmcli conn`.

Comment: network manager supports it, so I'm using that now. You were right, `bond0` is not in the `ip a` list. I thought that ifconfig was supposed to create that interface or something

Answer (score 1):

So the whole thing is called "bonding" and the network manager gui will support it in 1.34 (see https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/network-manager-applet/-/issues/140)

In the meantime, the `nm-cli` commands from https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/504465/227331 helped me. I'm using the "round-robin" mode.

It works really well, unscrewing the antenna makes the internet go over the powerline-ethernet automatically. i.e. whenever one of the two connections is disrupted there will be a fallback connection. Speedtest gives me good results when the wifi is connected, and slow results when antennas are unscrewed due to the powerline limitations, which is exactly what I wanted.